# Struggling with runtime setup of some castle components

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

My question (I think) can be simply described by this question:

**How can I get a "Manager" class to have a list of all possible concrete implementations of a specific interface that have been registered as components injected into it so it can iterate through them?** *(And because of annoying architecture reasons I can't use the app.config to register my components - so runtime registration only I guess)*

**EDIT:**
Ah hah! - Discovered that I can pass in my own configuration file using something like:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter("filename"));
```

so - I can just use the xml config route I stated below - this means that I don't have to worry about the instantiation of the child objects as they have injected dependencies themselves in my Real Life situation.

**EDIT:**

To try and aid your understanding of my issue though, I've set out below a simple repro showing my confusion! (Please forgive the terrible domain concept!)

This is a simple console app that has a manager that will run an action on a list of objects that it's given.

**The code:**

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter());
        var manager = container.Resolve<AnimalManager>();
        manager.PokeAnimals();
        container.Release(manager);
    }
}

public interface IMakeNoise {
    void MakeNoise();
}

public class Cat : IMakeNoise {
    public void MakeNoise() {
        Console.WriteLine("Meow");
    }
}

public class Dog : IMakeNoise {
    public void MakeNoise() {
        Console.WriteLine("Woof");
    }
}

public class AnimalManager {
    private readonly IList<IMakeNoise> noisemakers = new List<IMakeNoise>();

    public AnimalManager(IList<IMakeNoise> noisemakers) {
        this.noisemakers = noisemakers;
    }

    public void PokeAnimals() {
        foreach (var noisemaker in noisemakers) {
            noisemaker.MakeNoise();
        }
    }
}
```

**The config file** used looks like:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="castle" type="Castle.Windsor.Configuration.AppDomain.CastleSectionHandler, Castle.Windsor"/>
</configSections>

<castle>
  <components>
    <component id="Dog" service="CastleListTest.IMakeNoise, CastleListTest"
          type="CastleListTest.Dog, CastleListTest" />

    <component id="Cat" service="CastleListTest.IMakeNoise, CastleListTest"
          type="CastleListTest.Cat, CastleListTest" />

    <component id="AnimalManager" service="CastleListTest.AnimalManager, CastleListTest"
      type="CastleListTest.AnimalManager, CastleListTest">
      <parameters>
        <noisemakers>
          <list>
            <item>${Cat}</item>
            <item>${Dog}</item>
          </list>
        </noisemakers>
      </parameters>
    </component>
  </components>
</castle>
```

**My Problem:**

The above all works fine. However I can't define in an xml config file which kind of noisemakers I have. I won't know until runtime whether I have a cat, dog, 2 cats and a goldfish or whatever...

The only way I can see of doing this is best described by the code below. The problem with this is that I'm having to instantiate my NoiseMakers: "Dog" and "Cat". This seems wrong, against Castle, and in my actual example, it's something I really don't want to do. So what am I doing wrong? **How can I get a "Manager" class to have a list of all possible concrete implementations of a specific interface that have been registered as components injected into it so it can iterate through them?**

```
        var container = new WindsorContainer();

        container.AddComponent("Dog", typeof(IMakeNoise), typeof(Dog));
        container.AddComponent("Cat", typeof(IMakeNoise), typeof(Cat));
        container.AddComponent(
            "AnimalManager", typeof(AnimalManager), typeof(AnimalManager)
            );

        IList<IMakeNoise> noisemakers = new List<IMakeNoise> {new Dog(), new Cat()};

        var manager = container.Resolve<AnimalManager>(
            new Hashtable { { "noisemakers", noisemakers } }
            );

        manager.PokeAnimals();
        container.Release(manager);
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest thing to do is implement a SubDependancyResolver to resolve arrays then pass in the type in a construtor.

taken from [hammett blog](http://hammett.castleproject.org/?p=257)

```
public class ArrayResolver : ISubDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IKernel kernel;

    public ArrayResolver(IKernel kernel)
    {
          this.kernel = kernel;
    }

    public object Resolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver parentResolver,
                          ComponentModel model,
                          DependencyModel dependency)
    {
         return kernel.ResolveAll(dependency.TargetType.GetElementType(), null);
    }

    public bool CanResolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver parentResolver,
                          ComponentModel model,
                          DependencyModel dependency)
    {
          return dependency.TargetType != null &&
        dependency.TargetType.IsArray &&
        dependency.TargetType.GetElementType().IsInterface;
    }
}

public class AnimalManager
{
     private readonly IAnimal[] _animals;
     public AnimalManager(IAnimal[] animals)
     {
         _animals = animals
     }
}    

//Setup container somewhere
public IWindsorContainer ConfigureContainer()
{
     IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer().Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<Cat>());
     container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(typeof(ArrayResolver));

     IAnimalManager manager = container.Resolve<AnimalManager>();
}
```

The container will now inject all the the animal types into the AnimalManager class for you to use.

Colin G

Comment: ArrayResolver now comes included

Comment: Appreciated you took the time to answer Colin thanks! Even nicer to know that it's even easier now ArrayResolver is included :)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like the following, this allows me to register every implementation of the interface 'IAnimal' and then use 'ResolveAll' to get all implementations back as collection.

Hope it helps

Ollie

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Register(AllTypes.Pick().FromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).AllowMultipleMatches());

        var dog = container.Resolve<Dog>();
        var animals = container.ResolveAll<IAnimal>();
    }
}

public interface IAnimal
{
}

public class Dog : IAnimal
{
}

public class Cat : IAnimal
{
}

public class Fish : IAnimal
{
}
```